# Spark can't connect to YARN resource manager after adding Kafka jar

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to hook Spark up with Kafka. Previously, Spark worked correctly but did not have this functionality. I installed the `spark-streaming-kafka-spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly` jar into my jars folder for Spark, and now when I try to submit a task I get

```
INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); 
retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

The job hangs while it keeps trying to connect. I have yarn-site.xml that specifies the resource manager IP address - it has

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm1</name>
  <value>my.Server.Name:8032</value>
</property>
```

So it seems that the address is being overwritten - I am not sure why or how I can prevent this.

Update: If I move the jar outside of the Jar folders and include it with --jars instead, I don't get the hang. However, when I try to create a direct Kafka stream I get `n error occurred while calling o28.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce`. I'm not sure if this is a version mismatch or what.

Comment: Check whether all dependencies are added for same scala version. Either 2.10 or 2.11.

Comment: provide full pom or build.sbt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading the jar to the correct version - 2.11/2.1.0. You also need to have it outside of the Spark jars folder.